# How to wrap every 3rd <td> with a <tr> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to wrap `<tr>` tags around every 3rd `<td>`. Is there a way to do so?

**Html**

```
<table id="tblOne">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the output to be something like this:

```
<table id="tblOne">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var td = $("#tblOne td");                    // Getting all td
td.each(function(i){                         // Looping the td 
    if (i % 3 == 0) {                        // Splitting td as multiple of 3
        td.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll('<tr/>')    // Wrapping it inside tr
    }
}).parent('tr').unwrap();                    // Remove parent tr
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/ZyFUU/18/)**

Comment: Careful: infinite loop.

Comment: `$("#tblOne td:nth-child(3n)").append("<tr/>")` isn't enough ?

Comment: @dfsq I have updated the code. I was working on the demo then only I found the infinite loop. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can play with your HTML `table` by using JQuery [.each()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=each) and [.insertAfter()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=insertAfter) methods:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="insert">
Insert a TR after each third row
</button>

<button type="button" id="remove_and_re_insert">
Remove Old Trs and Re Insert a TR after each third row
</button>

<button type="button" id="remove">
Just Remove Old Trs
</button>

<table id="tblOne" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT/JQUERY:

```
// add click listener to button

$('#remove').click(function() {
   // removing old TRs
   if( $(".newTrs").length > 0 ){
    $(".newTrs").remove();
    alert("Old added New TRs removed");
   }else{   
    alert("There are no old added TRs");
   }
});

$('#remove_and_re_insert').click(function() {
   // removing old TRs
   if( $(".newTrs").length > 0 ){
    $(".newTrs").remove();
    alert("Old added New TRs removed");
   }else{   
    alert("There are no old added TRs");
   }
   doAddTrs();
   alert("New TRs inserted!");
});

$('#insert').click(function() {
   doAddTrs();
});

function doAddTrs(){
    // Looping Trs in the table #tblOne
    $('#tblOne tbody tr').each(function(key, element) {
     if( parseInt(key+1) % 3 == 0 ){
      // Inserting new Custom Tr HTML
      $( "<tr class='newTrs'><td>New 1</td><td>New 1</td></tr>" ).insertAfter(element);
        console.log(key, element);
     }     
   });
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wb4b0zpL/1/

Comment: Before down-voting, see how many functionality it is covering. It may help some-other coder :)